# EF Core transaction retry dbcontext creation policy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transactions

I'm not sure if I need to create a new `DbContext` instance using `IDbContextFactory` on each retry for a transaction in `IExecutionStrategy`. I didn't see other people do this, and it confuses me because not doing so can cause bugs, such as [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6496).

So, do I need to create a new instance of DbContext each time I retry a transaction in `IExecutionStrategy`?

In my case i have idempotency token check that throws exception when it retry and tries to add idempotency token with id that already persist inside change tracker of `DbContext`

```cs
var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
await ExecutionStrategyExtensions.ExecuteInTransactionAsync(
    strategy,
    new EmptyState(),
    async (_, _) =>
    {
        var idempotencyToken = new IdempotencyToken(token);
        _context.Add(idempotencyToken);

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException exception)
        {
            // idempotency token staff
        }
        
        // rest of code
    },
    async (_, _) => false,
    async (c, _) => await c.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(isolationLevel));
```

Better example:

```cs
strategy.ExecuteAsync(
    async () =>
    {
        await using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync;
        var user = new User(
            id: 0,
            name: "biba");

        context.Add(user);

        // Here can be thrown TimoutException and IExecutionStrategy will retry
        var products = await context.Products.ToListAsync();

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
```

There is a place where dbcontext can throw a transient exception and when we retray, a second user will be added to the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what scenarios you want to guard against and the meaning of a retry.

A retry scenario is usually used for situations where there is the possibility of a transient failure. Something like a timeout or locking issue. The system happened to be too busy, so try again.

Something like a Db Update exception is not a transient issue. It's like dialing a phone and getting the wrong number. Maybe you just entered it wrong, or wrote it down wrong, or the number is no longer in service. If all you do is hit the re-dial button, you're never going to get a different result. If you got an "engaged" response, then a redial a few minutes later may end up getting through.

When it comes to DbContexts you need to think much on the same lines. If you get something like a `DbUpdateException` this means you are now faced with a poisoned DbContext. The change tracker is tracking all inserts, updates, and deletes you have made, and one or more of these represent a "wrong number" scenario. It's up to you to try and resolve at runtime what is wrong and discard it, or replace those changes before attempting to save again. This can be fairly tricky if your operations are not particularly atomic, updating larger entity graphs. Clearing poisoned entities can be done by detaching them once you have identified the suspects, to be excluded, or reloaded + re-modified, or you can try making adjustments to the tracked entity state.  Usually a retry scenario goes back to the user as an error, where their data is reloaded and they re-attempt the operation as the typical cause is that their original data was stale. (Where the cause isn't a bug in the application/service)  The easiest way is typically to drop the DbContext and re-create a fresh one to wipe anything from the change tracking cache. Otherwise you need to manually go through everything currently in the tracking cache and detach it, reloading anything representing an existing record as well to purge any potentially invalid modified values. This doesn't occur automatically.

Edit:

Scoping the DbContext to allow for retrying as a unit of work:

```
strategy.ExecuteAsync(
    async () =>
    {
        using var context = _contextFactory.Create();
        var user = new User(
            id: 0,
            name: "biba");

        context.Add(user);

        // Here can be thrown TimoutException and IExecutionStrategy will retry
        // Why would you load all products and not await??
        var products = context.Products.ToListAsync();
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
```

So we don't use a module level injected DbContext instance (context) in this pattern. Instead we inject a DbContextFactory and use that to scope a DbContext within the strategy execution. If the execution fails and we want to retry, that DbContext is disposed, there is no duplicate data, no poisoned DbContext.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the example I provided is confusing. In the catch block, I'm searching for a unique constraint violation, and if it's not that kind of exception, I throw an exception, and the IExceptionStrategy does its work (catches the exception and, if it's transient, retries).

My question is, do I need to recreate a new DbContext for each retry in the IExceptionStrategy? The reason I think I need to is that otherwise, the DbContext will keep the change tracker from the previous retry and it can lead to those scenarios https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6496.

Comment: @Not_Ilya I think what Steve tries to explain here is that retry policies are aimed at recognizing typical transient failures and automatically retrying requests if they occur. It should suffice to set them in the EF configuration and then forget about them. You don't need to do this heavy lifting of recognizing transient failures. Just focus on business logic errors, which typically are *not* transient but require a solution. This solution usually means that an action is retried entirely with different parameters. That's not just a new context, it's a completely new request.

Comment: I understand and i agree with that. But im asking only about cases of transient errors and do i need to create a new DbContext when IExecutionStrategy does a retry. I didnt see people do so but i think that its required since otherwise on retry after transient error you will have DbContext with change tracker from previos retry.

Comment: I provided better example

Comment: I guess the point is: don't do this in an execution strategy. What do you gain by that? There's no point in retrying non-transient errors.

Comment: Yes, if your strategy patterns is to be treated as a restart-able unit of work, then the DbContext should be scoped to that unit of work, within the scope of the strategy execution. So for instance, using something like a DbContextFactory rather than a per-lifetime scope DbContext, or a Unit Of Work pattern that manages the lifetime scope of the DbContext to within the execution, rather than outside of it.  Keep in mind you may want to define aggregate roots for related entities so related entities are all comitted within a single call.

Comment: I didn't mention that I retry non-transient exceptions. I am aware that using the same DbContext between retries can lead to unintended behavior. The second example illustrates that after a transient exception on the second retry, two users will be added to the DbContext and when committing the transaction, two users will be written to the database instead of the expected one. The only way to prevent this is by recreating the DbContext between retries. However, I haven't seen other people do this, so it looks like I might be missing something.

Comment: I updated the answer to outline what I mean by scoping for the unit of work to facilitate the retry without a poisoned DbContext.

Comment: @StevePy Thanks for response. I dont understand why ef core doesnt have recreation of DbContext by default. I noticed a lot of people often expect that on retry their DbContext *forgets* about previos retries and they have those hard to catch rare bugs when multiple entities added to db.

Comment: @StevePy sorry i made a mistake about not awaiting, i fixes original question

Comment: *I dont understand why ef core doesnt have recreation of DbContext by default.* -- How would EF be able to replace a context instance all by itself and how would it decide when to do it? Even if it could, there are retries in which you want to reuse the context's content, but also, the context doesn't *know* that it runs in a retry block. Anyway, an alternative is to call `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` at the beginning of the block if you don't want to replace the context instance.